# Django changing model value based on relationship with other model

Tags: python, django

I'm working on a project that has three models, one of which has a value that is dependent on if the other two are linked to it by a foreign key. the value can also switch if the links change. I was wondering how I would go about that.

For example:

general/models.py

```
class Person(models.Model):
    DEFAULT = 'D'
    A = 'A'
    B = 'B'
    BOTH = 'AB'
    TYPES = [
        (DEFAULT,'Default'),
        (A,'Type A'),
        (B,'Type B'),
        (BOTH,'Type A & B')
    ]
    # type is default if Person is not linked to A or B
    # A if Person is linked to A
    # B if Person is linked to B
    # BOTH if Person is linked to both
    type = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=TYPES, default=DEFAULT)
```

A/models.py

```
class A(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey('general.Person',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

B/models.py

```
class B(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey('general.Person',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should override the [save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.save) method of models A and B in order to modify the ForeignKey like this:

```
class A(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey('general.Person',on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.person.type == Person.B:
             self.person.type=Person.AB
             self.person.save()
        # elif...
```